# Laravel 5.6: Customise a paginated resource collection meta and links attributes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-resource

How can I **customize Laravel ResourceCollection meta and links** information.

**Links** should include **only prev,next and self** instead of first,last,prev,next that is by default.

**Meta** should include pagination iformation like: **current_page, total_items, items_per_page, total_pages** instead of current_page, from, last_page, path, per_page, to, total.

This is how meta and links information looks now in JSON response:

```
"meta": {
    "currentPage": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 3,
    "path": "http://localhost:8000/api",
    "per_page": 5,
    "to": 5,
    "total": 14
},
"links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:8000/api",
    "first": "http://localhost:8000/api?page=1",
    "last": "http://localhost:8000/api?page=3",
    "prev": null,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api?page=2"
}
```

.. I want it to be something like:

```
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_items": 15,
    "per_page": 5,
    "total_pages": 3
},
"links": {
    "prev": null,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/api?page=2"
    "self": "http://localhost:8000/api",
}
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 7):

I have not been a fan with how Laravel has implemented paginators and resources, as its difficult to do certain things like the issue that you mentioned.

### Internals

Before you can customise your responses in the way you want, you first need to understand how ResourceCollections are converted to responses.

The original `toResponse` method for resource collections looks like this:

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    return $this->resource instanceof AbstractPaginator
                ? (new PaginatedResourceResponse($this))->toResponse($request)
                : parent::toResponse($request);
}
```

If you look in further into `PaginatedResourceResponse` class you will see the following code.

```
...
protected function paginationLinks($paginated)
{
    return [
        'first' => $paginated['first_page_url'] ?? null,
        'last' => $paginated['last_page_url'] ?? null,
        'prev' => $paginated['prev_page_url'] ?? null,
        'next' => $paginated['next_page_url'] ?? null,
    ];
}
...

protected function meta($paginated)
{
    return Arr::except($paginated, [
        'data', 
        'first_page_url',
        'last_page_url',
        'prev_page_url',
        'next_page_url',
    ]);
}
```

I recommend reading `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\PaginatedResourceResponse` and `Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceResponse` fully to understand what's going on.

### Solution 1: Create a custom PaginatedResourceResponse

One solution is to create a new class that extends `PaginatedResourceResponse`, and override the `paginationLinks` method.

So it look something like:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\PaginatedResourceResponse;

class CustomPaginatedResourceResponse extends PaginatedResourceResponse
{
    protected function paginationLinks($paginated)
    {
        return [
            'prev' => $paginated['prev_page_url'] ?? null,
            'next' => $paginated['next_page_url'] ?? null,
        ];
    }

    protected function meta($paginated)
    {
        $metaData = parent::meta($paginated);
        return [
            'current_page' => $metaData['current_page'] ?? null,
            'total_items' => $metaData['total'] ?? null,
            'per_page' => $metaData['per_page'] ?? null,
            'total_pages' => $metaData['total'] ?? null,
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you can override your `toResponse` method to look something like:

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    return $this->resource instanceof AbstractPaginator
                ? (new CustomPaginatedResourceResponse($this))->toResponse($request)
                : parent::toResponse($request);
}
```

You may consider overriding overriding other methods if you want to customise your response further.

### Solution 2: Override `toResponse` in the ResourceCollection

Instead of overriding the `PaginatedResourceResponse`, you can just override the `toResponse` method in the ResourceCollection with a lightweight version of similar code like so:

```
public function toResponse($request)
{
    $data = $this->resolve($request);
    if ($data instanceof Collection) {
        $data = $data->all();
    }

    $paginated = $this->resource->toArray();
    // perform a dd($paginated) to see how $paginated looks like

    $json = array_merge_recursive(
        [
            self::$wrap => $data
        ],
        [
            'links' => [
                'first' => $paginated['first_page_url'] ?? null,
                'last' => $paginated['last_page_url'] ?? null,
                'prev' => $paginated['prev_page_url'] ?? null,
                'next' => $paginated['next_page_url'] ?? null,
            ],
            'meta' => [
                'current_page' => $metaData['current_page'] ?? null,
                'total_items' => $metaData['total'] ?? null,
                'per_page' => $metaData['per_page'] ?? null,
                'total_pages' => $metaData['total'] ?? null,
            ],
        ],
        $this->with($request),
        $this->additional
    );

    $status = $this->resource instanceof Model && $this->resource->wasRecentlyCreated ? 201 : 200;

    return response()->json($json, $status);
}
```

### Solution 3: Override `withResponse` method

A simpler, but perhaps less powerful option is to just override the `withResponse` at the resource collection like so:

```
public function withResponse($request, $response)
{
    $data = $response->getData(true);
    $prev = $data['links']['prev'];
    $next = $data['links']['next'];
    $self = $data['links']['self'];
    $data['links'] = compact('prev', 'next', 'self');
    $response->setData($data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Can you elaborate on how to do these overrides you've mentioned? I'm mostly interested in your second solution but not sure of the steps required to implement it. Where would I add the new `toResponse` method?

Comment: Nevermind, I worked it out with the help of this page - https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources

Comment: @Yahya Uddin can you please answer this question, your help will be appreciated, thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648599/api-resources-not-working-as-expectation-in-lumen-missing-pagination-attributes